# Не переключаются цвета в тернарном операторе на реакте

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня в проекте на React + TypeScript + TailwindCSS есть такой компонент:

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClassActive = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex mt-5 bg-magnolia justify-center py-4 rounded-lg">
      <span
        className={`font-medium ${
          isActive ? "text-coolGray" : "text-marineBlue"
        }`}
      >
        Monthly
      </span>
      <label
        className="relative inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer bg-marineBlue rounded-full mx-3"
        onClick={toggleClassActive}
      >
        <input id="checkboxToggle" type="checkbox" className="sr-only peer" onChange={toggleClassActive} />
        <div className="w-11 h-6 rounded-full peer-checked:after:translate-x-full after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all"></div>
      </label>
      <span
        className={`font-medium ${
          isActive ? "text-marineBlue" : "text-coolGray"
        }`}
      >
        Yearly
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleButton;
```

**Проблема**: Оно должно при клике на `label` менять состояние хука `useState` на противоположное, и следовательно менять цвета в `span`-ах, но оно не меняет.

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что происходит 2 вызова функции. Первое на лейбле, второе на input

Comment: Да, действительно это так. У меня 2 вызова. Я убрал на лейбле, и оставил только на Input-е, и оно заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: См хук `useState` не меняется, менять можно только состояние которое им "создано". Но для этого нужно вызывать `setActive()`. Его вызов есть только в функции `toggleClassActive` - проверь срабатывает ли она. Добавь в нее `console.log('toggleClassActive ')` и посмотри будет ли в консоли что-то показываться. ;)